# Asp.Net 2 items referencing each other gets into infinite loop

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cascadingdropdown

I'm trying to reference 2 CascadeDropDownFor to each other, because their values depend on each other. While doing this when one finishes loading the other one starts again and loop goes on:

```
@Form.Fields(Html.LabelFor(x => x.Item.FirstBusLineRouteStopId),
Html.CascadeDropDownFor(x => x.Item.FirstBusLineRouteStopId)
    .With<TicketSalesController>(x => x.FirstBusLineRouteStops(null,null))
    .Reference(x => x.Item.BusLineTemplateId,"id")
    .Reference(x => x.Item.LastBusLineRouteStopId, "lastId")
    .Items(Model.FirstBusLineRouteStops)
    .WithEmptySelection().Large())
@Form.Fields(Html.LabelFor(x => x.Item.LastBusLineRouteStopId),
Html.CascadeDropDownFor(x => x.Item.LastBusLineRouteStopId)
    .With<TicketSalesController>(x => x.LastBusLineRouteStops(null,null))
    .Reference(x => x.Item.BusLineTemplateId,"id")
    .Reference(x => x.Item.FirstBusLineRouteStopId, "firstId")
    .Items(Model.LastBusLineRouteStops)
    .WithEmptySelection().Large())
```

In which way should I do this?

Comment: Well, it sort of makes sense, right? What are the semantics you're looking for? How should it behave?

Comment: I know, it does, thats's why I'm looking for solution. They should still reference each other, since the values depend on each other

Comment: It's hard to get the context. Does the 2nd one fire some event after it loads that tells the 1st one to load again? If so, can you set a flag to test so you can stop the loop?

Comment: After it loads the first one, the secod thinks it changed and it starts loading again etc Loop goes on. Nothing more is happening, but the data reloading

Comment: @aygul Sorry, I could use more clarification. Does the infinite loop start after the initial page loads and you select a value from the first (or second) drop list? If so, do you do a post back or an ajax call for the other droplist? Or am I asking all the wrong questions? =(